# phpMyAdmin Hosted in Azure problems

Tags: php, azure, phpmyadmin, azure-storage, azure-connect

I created my **phpMyadmin** in Windows Azure which only allows **1 MySQL database for free users**.

After creating a phpMyAdmin I **linked MySQL Database Resources** to another Website.

In this website I try to login my accounts registered to the database.

At first it goes smooth and seems there is no problem, but as i try to continue accessing  the website which  retrieves details from the linked MySQL Database Resources, The website returns and error of..

```
User 'b48a56f527c793' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 4)
```

But after a while 3-5mins the connection is good again.

At first I think the **Windows Azure** just tries to limit traffic but is it really that real cause of the problem or did i made **mistake in setting up my phpMyAdmin** in Windows Azure?

How to fix that error?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you use MySQL on Azure you have to know is it provided by ClearDB, and the free tier is very limited. You can [check the limitations here](https://www.cleardb.com/store/azure). For example you only have 4 concurrent connections limit, which is quite restrictive.

As a suggestion - never use `mysql_pconnect` in your scripts, but always use `mysql_connect` and **always** kill your connection when you don't need it anymore (i.e. when you retrieve the data).

I'm not 100% sure, but I think default installation of phpMyAdmin uses `mysql_pconnect`, which might keep idle connections as a resource from these 4 you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ClearDb on Azure which is the default option, ClearDb has really tight limit for simultaneous connections. Check it here:

https://www.cleardb.com/store/azure